# JBoss nodes not joining tcp standalone cluster

Tags: tcp, jboss, cluster-computing, jboss6.x, unicast

I am trying to setup a Standalone, TCP cluster.
I am not able to see the two nodes join the cluster.

The process snapshots are as below:

jboss    21682 11484  0 07:56 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.21.141.109
jboss    21789 21682  1 07:56 pts/0    00:00:38 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/jboss-modules.jar -mp /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.21.141.109

jboss    28082 25185  0 07:56 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.21.142.37
jboss    28173 28082  0 07:56 pts/0    00:00:27 java -D[Standalone] -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.modules.policy-permissions=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/jboss-modules.jar -mp /data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/data/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.21.142.37

server.log entries:

*07:56:57,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
07:56:57,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) GMS: address=pkumarips045001/web, cluster=web, physical address=10.21.141.109:7600
07:56:57,758 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
07:56:57,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67)
07:56:57,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
07:56:57,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) GMS: address=pkumarips045001/web, cluster=web, physical address=10.21.141.109:7600
07:56:57,758 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
07:57:00,776 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [pkumarips045001/web|0] [pkumarips045001/web]*

Request your assistance with this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by changing the bind address. Now I can see both nodes in the cluster.

I am having some errors with HornetQ and modcluster. Again, seems like something related to the bind address. 
Will look further into it.

Thank you.